# Why JavaScript map function return undefined at the first time?

Tags: reactjs

while trying to map over users array of objects and spread every user and add new property I
got an array of undefined then I got the needed array after adding the new property.

```js
    const newUsers = users?.map(user => {
        for (let provider of providers) {
            if (!user.providerId) {
                return { ...user, providerName: null };
            }
            if (provider.ID === user.providerId) {
                return { ...user, providerName: provider.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME };
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(" ~ file: Users.js ~ line 44 ~ Users ~ newUsers", newUsers);
```

[output in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnwd1.png)

Comment: If there is a `user.providerId` but `provider.ID !== user.providerId`, you aren't returning anything, so it goes on to the next iteration of the loop. But if none of the iterations of your `for` loop result in a `return`, you will end up with an `undefined` in your new array.

Comment: .map() always returns a value, in case both ifs are not true, it will return undefined for this iteration.

Comment: @DBS is totally right, I think. Please check your providers.

Comment: As a side note, a `for` loop inside a `map` is a little confusing to read. You could move the first `if` out of the loop and replace the entire loop with a `const match = providers.find(p => p.ID === user.providerId)` and an `if(match) { return ... }`